# wget not following links with spider

Tags: wget, web-crawler

I am trying to check a page and all of its links as well as images.
The following is stopping after the initial page and I get very little output.

```
wget -v -r --spider -o /Users/SSSSS/Desktop/file21.txt http://www.WWWWWWW.com/SSSSSS/index.php
```

Comment: It works for me. You should show the output.